# What's the meaning of this line in a Qt .pro file?

Tags: c++, qt

I downloaded some code from https://github.com/ialhashim/GeoTopo and want to run it in my `QtCreator`. In the `.pro` file there is this line:

```
Warningswin32{QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= /wd4800 /wd4244 /wd4267}
```

It seems like about warning. Later the program failed with:

```
no such file or directory /wd4800 /wd4244 /wd4267
```

I removed these lines and found there are also some lines for Parallelism :

```
win32{
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= /openmp
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= /MP
}
```

And I got same error "no such file or directory /openmp"
I wonder how could I handle this error?

Comment: If you take that line out of the pro file, does it compile then?  Can you post the link to the code or the code itself?  Also, did you qmake the project before trying to compile it?

Comment: @tornesi the link to the code is https://github.com/ialhashim/GeoTopo . I qmake the project before compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Qt project statement is not valid. You d'ont get any error when .pro file is being parsed by Qt Creator?

It's surely a code supposed to activate or inhibate some warnings on WIN32. The line should be something like (not tested):

```
win32 {
    # Then use QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON or QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF depending on what's intended
}
```

I recommend that you comment the line and compile. If it works that will be fine.

Comment: I tried to comment this line ,but found other lines similar. And I don't want to   simply ignore them. I found the code in https://github.com/ialhashim/GeoTopo

Comment: `win32` may be too generic, maybe they wrote their .pro file for a specific Windows compiler (MinGW for instance) and you are using a different one (Visual Studio for instance) that does not support the same options....